# Add multiple parameters to URL API fetch in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, fetch-api

I am trying to add multiple parameters to a API fetch using `Redux`. I am able to get one to work (`maxDist` you see below in the API call), but I want to add the `minStars` and `maxRes` parameters as well, but am unsure how I would add more than one. I tried adding more parameters to the `search()` function, but it will only use one argument. Here is what I have so far:

**API Call:**

```
export default {
  search(maxDist) {
    const url = `${API_URL}&maxDistance=${maxDist}&minStars=${minStars}&maxResults=${maxRes}`;
    console.log(url);
    return fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
        return result.items;
      });
  }
};
```

**Redux Side:**

```
const MAX_DIST_CHANGED = "MAX_DIST_CHANGED";

const initialState = {
  items: [],
  maxDist: "",
  minStars: "",
  maxRes: ""
};

export const actions = {
  maxDistChanged(maxDist) {
    return {
      type: MAX_DIST_CHANGED,
      maxDist
    };
 getItems(maxDist) {
    return {
      type: "ITEMS",
      payload: API.search(maxDist)
    };
  }
};

export function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case MAX_DIST_CHANGED: {
      return {
        ...state,
        maxDist: action.maxDist
      };
    }
 case "ITEMS_FULFILLED": {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        items: action.payload
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**App.js:**

```
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onGetItems(
      this.props.maxDist
    );
  };
  handleChange = event => this.props.onMaxDistChanged(event.target);

function mapDisatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onMaxDistChanged(maxDist) {
      dispatch(actions.maxDistChanged(maxDist));
    }
 onGetItems(maxDist) {
      dispatch(actions.getItems(maxDist));
    }
  };
}
```

How do I add the `minStars` and `maxRes` in the api call? Only one parameter seems to works.